# Sum Specific Child Element with Xpath But Exlude Other Ones By Filtering

Tags: xml, xpath, sum

To make it short i'm trying to do this:
Sum child elements in my case the "Priority"  but by excluding other Childs with a filter based on the specific text inside it. My Xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
   <MODELS>
      <MODEL>
         <MODELATTRIBUTES>
                <INSTANCE id="obj.22519" class="Ambulance" name="Ambulance-42632">
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Position" type="STRING">NODE x:9.5cm y:10.5cm w:1cm h:1.5cm index:66</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="External tool coupling" type="STRING"></ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Priority" type="INTEGER">20</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Direction" type="ENUMERATION">Vertical</ATTRIBUTE>
                </INSTANCE>
                <INSTANCE id="obj.22525" class="Police car" name="Police car-42638">
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Position" type="STRING">NODE x:9.5cm y:12.5cm w:1cm h:1cm index:68</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="External tool coupling" type="STRING"></ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Availability" type="ENUMERATION">Free</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Priority" type="INTEGER">60</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Direction" type="ENUMERATION">Vertical</ATTRIBUTE>
                </INSTANCE>
                <INSTANCE id="obj.22595" class="Car" name="Car-22595">
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Position" type="STRING">NODE x:3cm y:7cm w:1.5cm h:1cm index:88</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="External tool coupling" type="STRING"></ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Priority" type="INTEGER">2</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE name="Direction" type="ENUMERATION">Horizontal</ATTRIBUTE>
                </INSTANCE>
        </MODELATTRIBUTES>
    </MODEL>
  </MODELS>
</Test>
```

I actually can Sum all the Priority Values with this for example:

```
sum(//*[@name='Priority'][@type='INTEGER'])
```

I get

> 82

but i want to divide the Sum result in Vertical and Horizontal based on

```
<ATTRIBUTE name="Direction" type="ENUMERATION">Vertical</ATTRIBUTE>
```

and

```
<ATTRIBUTE name="Direction" type="ENUMERATION">Horizontal</ATTRIBUTE>
```

so how could i filter out the "Horzontal" Priority so that in the end i get only 80 as a final result for the "Vertical Priorities" ?

i have tried this aproach but it doen't work

```
sum(//*[@name='Priority'][@type='INTEGER'] [not(//*[text()='Horizontal'])])
```

Any Help is really appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get sum of vertical priority (formatted for readability):

```
sum(
    //INSTANCE[ATTRIBUTE[@name="Direction" and .='Vertical']]
     /ATTRIBUTE[@name='Priority'][@type='INTEGER']
)
```

Comment: You made my day, Thanks lot it worked flawlessly , I used the same query for the Horizontal to //INSTANCE[ATTRIBUTE[@name=\"Direction\" and .='Horizontal']]/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Priority'][@type='INTEGER'] )  finally i got the result that i wanted Thanks again and Have an awesome day :D